# Convert Active Record set into an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I saw this...

[How to convert activerecord results into a array of hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427936/how-to-convert-activerecord-results-into-a-array-of-hashes)

and wanted to create a method that would allow me to turn any scoped or non-scoped record set into an array of hashes.  I added this to my model:

```
 def self.to_hash
   to_a.map(&:serializable_hash)
 end
```

However, I get this error.

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `to_a' for #<Class:0x007fb0da2f2708>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably need to call `all` on that too. Just the `to_a` would work fine on a scope or existing result set (e.g. `User.active.to_hash`) but not directly on the model (e.g. `User.to_hash`). Using `all.to_a` will work for both scenarios.

```
def self.to_hash
  all.to_a.map(&:serializable_hash)
end
```

Note that the `all.to_a` is a little duplicative since `all` already returns an array, but in Rails 4 it will be necessary.

Comment: thank you, if you are up to the challenge, I am extremely stuck on this issue too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222379/calculate-percent-of-total-from-scoped-records-and-display-virtual-attributes-r

Answer (score 2):

You're performing the action on a class, not an instance of the class. You can either take away the `self.` then call this on an instance, or to call it on a collection you need to pass the collection into the class method:

```
def self.to_hash(collection)
  collection.to_a.map(&:serializable_hash)
end
```

Comment: I don't think he wants this performed on an instance of his class (i.e. one record), but rather on a result set.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, came to that conclusion also just after posting.

Comment: You can still use other scopes/queries. `User.active.to_hash` will still only return a hash of the active users. `all` doesn't reset the scope, but `unscoped` would. (Keep in mind this class method can be called on a scope/relation, it isn't restricted to being called only on the class itself like `User.to_hash`)