# How to get ActiveRecord::Result from ActiveRecord::Relation on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to leverage querying capabilities of my model but I want to load arbitrary aggregated values. `.pluck` will give me an array and I'll lose the reference to columns that I have on  `ActiveRecord::Result`.

So far I've been going through `connection` but that's cumbersome

```
query = where(...).group(...).select(...)
connection.exec_query(query.to_sql)
```

Comment: how about calling `.to_a` on the relation?? or `all`

Comment: I know your question is different from these others, but you might consider these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427936/how-to-convert-activerecord-results-into-a-array-of-hashes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225232/convert-active-record-set-into-an-array-of-hashes

Comment: @bjhaid as you can see I am using `GROUP` and I don't want to load instances of my model but aggregated data (counts, avgs...)

Comment: @rafb3 calling the aggregate function on the result would give you what you want